# I have to code excel sheet (all computation in sheet) into python. For problem reference I have attached image file

Tags: excel

[Excel file and formula for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pcum.jpg)

Based on all input (A, B, C), I have to compute for C column. First row value of column C, we have to  initialize with some value(user Input).

Comment: First understand the logic used in the sheet, then re-write the formulae to work in Python.

Comment: I understand the logic in excel but unable to write in python as I am new to python.....can you give me some clue or hints....

Comment: Perhaps start here: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/